# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' - In .NET Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am making a BookEvent app using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC. I am facing this error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.`

How can I fix it?

I am trying to display all created events at the home page.

#### File *HomeController.cs*

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AllEvents()
{
    var result = _eventAppService.GetAllEvent();
    var details = _mapper.Map<EventViewModel>(result.Data);

    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        this._logger.LogInformation(result.MainMessage.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        Message = $"About page visited at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()}";
        this._logger.LogError(Message);
        return View("Index");
    }
    return View(details);
}
```

#### File *EventAppServices.cs*

```
public OperationResult<IEnumerable<EventDTO>> GetAllEvent()
{
    IEnumerable<Event> eventList = _eventRepository.Get(x => x.IsActive).ToList<Event>();
    List<EventDTO> eventDTOList = new List<EventDTO>();
    eventDTOList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Event>, List<EventDTO>>(eventList);
    Message message = new Message(string.Empty, "Return Successfully");
    var eventslist =  new OperationResult<IEnumerable<EventDTO>>(eventDTOList, true, message);
    return eventslist;
}
```

#### File *Index.cshtml*

[image]

#### File EventViewModel.cs

```
public class EventViewModel : ViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required]

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public EventType eventTypes;

    [Display(Name = "Duration In Hours")]
    [Range(0, 4)] public virtual ICollection<UserEvent> UserEvent { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Other Details")]
    public string OtherDetails { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invite Others")]
    public string InviteByEmail { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us EventViewModel ?

Comment: @DarkkL L Added. Please check again

Comment: And you successfully map all to details ?

Comment: I didn't get any error there while mapping. Assuming that yes it is Successfully mapped

Comment: First of all debug the controller and be sure the ```details ``` if filled by you mapping whether it returns you an error or not !

Comment: I am not sure you successfully map ```OperationResult<IEnumerable<EventDTO>>``` to  ```IEnumerable<EventViewModel>```

Comment: @DarkkL Yes, it was not mapping properly. Thanks its solved now.

Comment: ok i will make the answer , you can give me a vote up if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your *mapping*  OperationResult<IEnumerable<EventDTO>> to IEnumerable. Make sure you map it correctly.